# Laravel Echo Get Listeners

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

anyway before event fire we check first if a user listens to the event ( like we in dashboard page we listen to the event ), so if we have a user in dashboard currently let event fire ! if not list event ( or set the job to failed ! for checking it later again ! if the user in dashboard job start and fire event ! if not again failed and wait to user listen to channel first ! )

I hope you guys understand what I mean!

Comment: Can’t you use a presence channel to determine whether a user is online or not by modifying the database when they connect and when they disconnect? Then just before you send an event, check whether the column is true (online) and send it?

Comment: @Savlon thanks for the answer and yeah, I think about that before when a user joins channel set a user to online and before sending an event check if the user online sends it! But I don't know its right way when I use socket and laravel echo!

Comment: the right way is the way that works. If you encounter issues with it then look for other ways to implement it, but I don’t see a problem at all with that. I’ve implemented something similar and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @salvon thanks again, now I have a problem! I want to send details to a page with X name, and on this page, the user listens to the channel ( without login ). Every user has a unique token, so I use this token for authorizing users! They don't need to log in! so do you have any idea what I must do now? :| confused now :|. All think I want to do is after event start if a user listens to page ( URL set with user token so user, not log in) show him data if don't fire event and store data in DB when user come back and listen to channel ill send a failed events for this user! hope you understand xD

Comment: I don’t quite understand what purpose this has and it sounds like a different question, so might be best if you ask another question and put in a lot of detail with code snippets if you can